# Problem with installing grunt (lodash@0.9.2)

Tags: install

I have iMac (ElCapitan) for few days and I try to install all needs for my work (templating for WordPress).

I try to install grunt, but I got WARN messages in terminal and I am absolutely out of what they mean:

```
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.
```

I have no idea, if that is problem in my computer, or grunt. I try to search by google, but I did not find any suitable answer or better answer which can clear this for me.
...will I need upgrade lodash@?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so it is just warning and grunt is installed. Yesterday was not present in system, but when I check now by grunt --version, I got answer about version of installed grunt.

I got confirmation on Github.